# URL Rewriting with Dynamic Pages and Static Pages

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have been trying to write a .htaccess file that removes the .php extension from all files, and also deals with the dynamic News page.
I have been able to remove the .php extension, but I would also like the to have /news/{name} redirect to /article.php?slug={name}. It would also be great to have /news work to keep the list of news articles.

I've tried many variants, but my current .htaccess that doesn't work is:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^news/([^/]+)/?$ article.php?slug=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the fix is as simple as using

`RewriteRule ^/news/..........`

Comment: I was thinking that might be it, but it still doesn't work. I also was thinking it may have been a RegEx error, but that doesn't fix it either.